# Is it possible to Connect API Twitter with Endeca 3.0?

Tags: twitter, endeca

I read something about possibly connecting the Twitter Api with Endeca 3.0 through the HTTP Connecter, but I am not sure if it is feasible or possible. Would it be possible to set this up to automatically pull tweets from an account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Oracle learning library. [https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0::NO:24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:7720,2](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0%3a%3aNO:24%3aP24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:7720,2)