# Twitter data to Endeca Studio - Complete process

Tags: json, twitter, endeca

I have been trying to find out how to get Twitter feeds via Twitter API to Integrator and eventually to Studio.

I have successfully been able to setup the API and now I have relevant tweets in a json file.

But I am clueless about how do i get this data to the studio. This json file contains all kind of information about the tweets (Who, where, when how etc) in addition to the Tweet text itself.

I need to get these tweets into the endeca studio.

Please help me out here. Any help would be great.

Thanks & Regards,
Naman

Comment: Have you had a look at the tutorial in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074800/is-it-possible-to-connect-api-twitter-with-endeca-3-0) answer?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you do not want them in Dev Studio, but you want them incorporated into your index.

If that is indeed the case, you need to bring them in via either an xml file or database, unless someone has created a json adapter to perform the task.

Then you will be able to search the tweets like you would any other record in your endeca index.

Good luck.

Comment: I actually think he meant the [Endeca Information Discovery Studio](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39271_01/index.htm) and not Developer Studio